# Triple monitor setup - what determines the configuration under Win+P options in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have two PC screens and a TV connected to a single graphics card. It worked alright until recently, I used to have it so that when I press Win+P, the option "Second screen only" would give me the two PC screens, TV off. "PC screen only" would give me just the TV, PC monitors off. Not my preference, but I got used to it.

Then it suddenly changed, with no apparent reason. It became so that "Second screen only" is TV only, to have the two PC monitors and no TV is now the "Extend" option.

I did a Windows reinstall and it worked for a while the first way, then it switched, again without any obvious reason, to the second way. I wonder: what determines the screen configuration under the individual Win+P options? If I try to set it for, say, "Second screen only" and change the configuration the way I want (be it through the Nvidia control panel or Windows 10's Display settings), the active Win+P option changes as well. Of course, a direct way to edit the configurations for Win+P options would be most welcome.